# IP address and Country on same line with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm looking for a one-liner that based on a list of IPs will append the country from where the IP is based

So if I have this as and input:

```
87.229.123.33
98.12.33.46
192.34.55.123
```

I'd like to produce this:

```
87.229.123.33 - GB
98.12.33.46 - DE
192.34.55.123 - US
```

I've already got a script that returns the country for IP but I need to glue it all together with awk, so far this is waht I came up with:

```
$ get_ips | nawk '{ print $1; system("ip2country " $1) }'
```

This is all cool but the ip and the country are not displayed on the same line, how can I merge the system output and the ip on one line ?

If you have a better way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: By the way, I'm interested in your ip2country script. Is it public? If you can share it, maybe you can start a question for that and answer it yourself.

Comment: amarillion, ip2country is my alias for this: /usr/bin/geoiplookup $1 | awk -F', ' '{print $NF}'  
, I use MaxMinds free public database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper one-liner solution in awk is:

```
awk '{printf("%s - ", $1) ; system("ip2country \"" $1 "\"")}' < inputfile
```

However I think it would be much faster if You would use a python program looking like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# 'apt-get install python-geoip' if needed
import GeoIP
gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
for line in file("ips.txt", "r"):
    line = line[:-1] # strip the last from the line
    print line, "-", gi.country_code_by_addr(line)
```

As You can see, the geoip object is initialized only once and then it is reused for all queries. See a [python binding for geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python). Also be aware that Your awk solution forks a new process 2 times per line!

I don't know how many entries You need to process, but if it's much of it, You should consider something that doesn't fork and keeps the geoip database in memory.

Comment: are you sure the ip2country shouldn't be inside quotes in the sysetm call ?

Comment: Right. There was a missing " in the system call. The thing about awk is that trouble with the quoting happens all the time, I once had to write an 80-char line with 56 of ", ` and ' characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *printf* instead of print:

```
{ printf("%s - ", $1); system("ip2country " $1); }
```

Comment: Should it really be "system(system(" ? Does this solution give output in the required format, "87.229.123.33 - GB"?

Comment: Oops, I removed the extra 'system' call. That was a typo.

Comment: Your solution outputs something like "87.229.123.33GB" and "192.34.55.123US".

Comment: Reef, you are right, I should have added " - " to the format string.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer with a perl one-liner because I know that syntax better than awk. The "chomp" will cut off the newline that is bothering you.

```
get_ips | perl -ne 'chomp; print; print `ip2country $_`'
```